# jQuery QRcode does not work with canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, qr-code

I'm using this library: https://larsjung.de/jquery-qrcode/ to draw a QR Code inside my canvas, but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
var a_canvas = document.getElementById("latoSinistro");
var context = a_canvas.getContext("2d");



context.font = "8px appMeFont";
context.textAlign="center"; 
context.fillText(dati.anagrafica[linguaInUso].prodName, 121, 93);
context.fillText(dati.anagrafica[linguaInUso].pointName, 121, 103);


$("#latoSinistro").qrcode({
    "render": 'canvas',
    "minVersion": 1,
    "maxVersion": 10,
    "ecLevel": 'M',
    "left": 121,
    "top": 130,
    "fill": '#000',
    "background": null,
    "mode": 0,
    "size": 100,
    "color": "#000000",
    "text": "www.app/cod/"+idProdotto
});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser's console? Is `latoSinistro` the id of your canvas element?

Comment: Your code is [working fine](https://jsfiddle.net/xf1q0r4m/), you should just adjust the positions. You should also check if your `dati` object values are correct.

Comment: i don't get any errors, latoSinistro is a canvas. the position i think is right because the 2 texts appears and dati value is correct. why don't see anything?

Comment: i have update the library and now works :D

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you have declare in your view

```
<div id="latoSinistro"
</div>
```

2. make sure your `var idProdotto` value has been assigned to make qr code generate clearly